# Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, streaming, pyspark

I have Spark Streaming in Pyspark with the "Batch interval" = 30 sec

```
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 30)
```

Then I would like to use window() function for getting the data for the last hour and slicing each 30 sec accross this data.

```
kvs = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [topic], {"metadata.broker.list": brokers})

counts = kvs.map(lambda (k, v): json.loads(v))\
            .map(TransformInData).window(108000)
```

and I have got an error

```
16/02/18 10:23:01 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1455790980000 ms
16/02/18 10:23:30 INFO PythonTransformedDStream: Slicing from 1455683040000 ms to 1455791010000 ms (aligned to 1455683040000 ms and 1455791010000 ms)
16/02/18 10:23:30 INFO PythonTransformedDStream: Time 1455790650000 ms is invalid as zeroTime is 1455790650000 ms and slideDuration is 30000 ms and difference is 0 ms
16/02/18 10:23:31 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1455791010000 ms
```

I have read this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spark-users/GQoxJHAAtX4
but I do not understand why it is not working

Comment: Which version of Spark are you using?

Comment: 1.6.0    version spark

Comment: Same Issue: I guess it is throwing "time is invalid .." as `time - ZeroTIme`(difference) of `isTimeValid()` method is 0 of Dstream class and that means `time = zeroTime` and hence `time <= zeroTime` returns true leading to `isTimeValid` method to `return false` with the above message.

Comment: I got the same issue while windowing one of the N dstreams and joining them with other. (Spark 1.6.0, scala 2.10.5, Hadoop 2.6)

Comment: can you make sure that your time zone is in sync. https://abdussamad.com/archives/343-CentOS-Linux:-Setting-timezone-and-synchronizing-time-with-NTP-.html

Comment: kvs = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [topic], {"metadata.broker.list": brokers})   , is this line is working ? for you

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem. Upgrading to Spark 2.0.1 fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes please upgrade to Spark 2.1
Then add `kafka frequency = 1000` in `ms` , and add `offset` in you `Dstream()`